# What are the advantages for the employer to set flexible hours?

Tags: software-industry, hours, france, working-conditions

My situation is quite similar to this question: [How To Negotiate Flexible Working Hours](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/11932/how-to-negotiate-flexible-working-hours)

In order to help me to "build my case" I wanted to know what are advantages for the employer to let their employees have flexible hours (with core hours).

Here are some example I already found:

- Better retention of employees
- Reduced turnover/absenteeism

Other context information:
 Small software company of about 15 employees located in France

**EDIT**
 I work full time on site

**EDIT 2**
Thank you to all of you, I will try to make an update about my request if you are interested.

Comment: There is only ever one advantage to employee perks: Employees want them, and it costs the employer less to give them the perk than to give them something else they value (such as a higher salary).

Comment: That is a very tough one, in France.

Comment: Can you explain, do you work on site or remotely?

Comment: @Fattie Full time on site (added on edit)

Comment: Flexible Schedule = Better Mental Health = Better Productivity = Increase in Profit

Comment: "Flexible schedule" = a benefit for programmers, much like "high salaries".  There is zero benefit for the employer; if there was it would be completely widespread everywhere.

Comment: @Fattie Anything that is not universal has zero benefit?  You have a demented logic.   Capitalism is not universal.  Does it have zero benefit?

Comment: "if there was it would be widespread" - very straightforward.

Comment: I think the best way to approach this is very company specific.  I recommend you research all the profit margins of the company and build your case specifically based on that.  You can get tons of points to mention, but unless you make it pertinent to the company and manager in question, you won't have the results you desire.  Those aren't in this question.

Comment: @Fattie It is widespread everywhere.  In an 17 year career I've never worked at somewhere that doesn't have flexible hours.  The number of places that don't have it to soe degree is single digit percents in this industry

Comment: @Fattie "if it worked, everyone would do it" implies that people and companies act rationally at all times, which is a laughable idea at best.

Comment: Because it may make software engineers more efficient ? For example, I am not a morning person. If I were asked to start at 8am, I'd pretty much be ineficient during the first 1 to 1.5 hour. So allowing a more flexible schedule may be a way for the employees to work when they're at their best which does result in a benefit for the employer.

Comment: @Fattie why especially in france?

Comment: @User632716 In France we have the law that regulate the working conditions ("Code du travail") and also working field conventions ("convention collective") that adds rules which is quite complicated.

Comment: @kenfire fair enough, that said I work in France, in a position with Flexible hours, so it's definitly possible- it seems all you have to do is request it (then track your hours): https://contrat-de-travail.ooreka.fr/astuce/voir/647479/horaires-variables

Comment: @User632716 In my case It's not really a legal problem but more a company culture change.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> What are the advantages for the employer to set flexible hours?

I would label them "potential" advantages:

- Employees like it, which may lead to decreased turnover
- Potential employees like it, which may make it easier to attract new workers
- In some cases, flexible hours may make it easier to provide coverage over a wider range of hours
- In some locales, workers will be able to arrange their hours to avoid longer commute times. That may allow them to remain more productive for longer
- In some cases, the other companies in the pool of companies that draw from the same worker base are already offering flexible hours. It may be necessary to offer this benefit or risk losing talent
- In some cases, it may make child care or other personal activities easier for the employee. That may help retain employees.

Comment: Unfortunately, employers of programmers simply see these as what they are, made-up advantages, rationales.  Employers no more like to give away these benefits to programmers, than they wish to give away high salaries to programmers, but the employers have to.  (In France in particular, the shortage in certain software fields is incredible.)

Comment: I agree that these are excellent reasons to justify the benefits (or actions - however you prefer to describe them) in question. I would just say that, with lots of experience in France, French employers would consider these "rationales" - to put it bluntly they would "laugh at" them (Again, purely in M.O.), and they would just consider it another demand (just as "a higher salary" is a demand).  Just M.O.

Comment: You are missing a couple - makes Child care easier. Also some people are morning people others are afternoon people.

Comment: Is that a benefit to both. A less stress employee and working at peak performance both good for all. Is it not "happy chickens hay good eggs"

Comment: But if you are a chicken it would be nice to be happy

Comment: @JoeStrazzere - How does a chicken smile with a beak?

Comment: Less stress for workers also means less sick time, which could be another benefit to the employers.

Comment: @fattie your first comment is an overgeneralization. Some employers will see it that way, others will not. Especially those employers who have needs that span outside the traditional 9-5 hours (eg dev teams in multiple time zones, etc).

Answer (score 2):

If this is a 9-5 business, there may never be an advantage for the employer.

After hours requests could be addressed:

1. Finishing a task that was requested at the end of the day.
2. Performing maintenance or repairs when others don't need their equipment.
3. Handling a customer request.

Negotiations usually involve some give and take. By giving you this perk, the employer may be in a position to ask you for something extra. The key would be to identify what is important to your employer in this area and make an offer.

Comment: +1 For "Performing maintenance or repairs when others don't need their equipment."

Answer (score 1):

The bigest advantage from flexible hours is much more motivation produced by [autonomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-determination_theory#Autonomy) :

> Situations that give autonomy as opposed to taking it away also have a
>   similar link to motivation. Studies looking at choice have found that
>   increasing a participant's options and choices increases their
>   intrinsic motivation

Answer (score 1):

If a company is looking for "bums on seats" then there is no advantage. Let's ignore that case.

When a company hires an employee, that employee will do work for the employer, and the employer will supply salary and possibly other benefits to the employee. The higher the salary and other benefits are, the better the chances to find an employee, and to find a better employee, and to keep them.

Flexible time costs the employer no or little money, but can be a huge benefit to the employee. And that's the kind of thing a company should be looking for: Giving the employee benefits other than salary, if they cost less than salary.

Some other answer talks about "ridiculous extras like food". If you have the space, providing free or cheap food to employees is *extremely* beneficial to the company. Every place in my experience where this happened, people counted it like salary (so it really gets you better talent and keeps that talent), while costing the company a lot less. And importantly, lunch breaks were shorter, people ate healthy which is good for the company, and people were often discussing work problems during lunch.

Answer (score 0):

These might help you make a case:

- [Study: Effects of working from home](https://people.stanford.edu/nbloom/sites/default/files/wfh.pdf). spoiler: WFH folks tend to be more productive.
- [Study: Employees with flexible work hours are healthier](https://www.theatlantic.com/health/archive/2011/12/study-of-the-day-employees-with-flexible-work-hours-are-healthier/250524/). Link to the full PDF can be found in the final paragraph.
- [Study: how flexible schedules can mitigate employee turnover](http://www.flexiblework.umn.edu/publications_docs/SocialProblems-Turnover-2011.pdf).
- [Several collected case studies involving flexible work schedules](http://scholarship.law.georgetown.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1007&context=legal).
- [Inside Three Companies That Are Innovating Flexible Schedules](https://www.fastcompany.com/3059295/inside-three-companies-that-are-innovating-flexible-schedules).